# Error in LightGBM algorithm using tidymodels and treesnip package

Tags: r, lightgbm, tidymodels

I want to try the LightGBM algorithm using tidymodels and treesnip package.
Some preproccessing...

```
# remotes::install_github("curso-r/treesnip")
        # install.packages("titanic") 
        library(tidymodels)
        library(stringr)
        library(titanic)
        data("titanic_train")

    df <- titanic_train %>% as_tibble %>%
      mutate(title=str_extract(Name,"\\w+\\.") %>% str_replace(fixed("."),"")) %>%
      mutate(title=case_when(title %in% c('Mlle','Ms')~'Miss', 
                             title=='Mme'~ 'Mrs',
                             title %in% c('Capt','Don','Major','Sir','Jonkheer', 'Col')~'Sir',
                             title %in% c('Dona', 'Lady', 'Countess')~'Lady',
                             TRUE~title)) %>%
      mutate(title=as.factor(title),
             Survived=factor(Survived,levels = c(0,1),labels=c("no","yes")),
             Sex=as.factor(Sex),
             Pclass=factor(Pclass)) %>%
      select(-c(PassengerId,Ticket,Cabin,Name)) %>% 
      mutate(Embarked=as.factor(Embarked))
table(df$title,df$Sex)

trnTst <- initial_split(data = df,prop = .8,strata = Survived)

cv.folds <- training(trnTst) %>% 
  vfold_cv(data = .,v = 4,repeats = 1)
cv.folds
rec <- recipe(Survived~.,data = training(trnTst)) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>%  
  step_knnimpute(Age,neighbors = 3,impute_with = vars(title,Fare,Pclass))
```

To check that the problem is not in the data, i succesfully tune the Random Forest algorithm.

```
m.rf <- rand_forest(trees = 1000,min_n = tune(),mtry = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode(mode = 'classification') %>% 
  set_engine('ranger')
wf.rf <- workflow() %>% add_recipe(rec) %>% add_model(m.rf)
(cls <- parallel::makeCluster(parallel::detectCores()-1))
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = cls)
tn.rf <- tune_grid(wf.rf,resamples = cv.folds,grid = 20,
                    metrics = metric_set(accuracy,roc_auc))
doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
autoplot(tn.rf)
wf.rf <- finalize_workflow(x = wf.rf,parameters = select_best(tn.rf,metric = 'roc_auc'))
res.rf <- fit_resamples(wf.rf,resamples = cv.folds,metrics = metric_set(accuracy,roc_auc))
res.rf %>% collect_metrics()
```

But lightGBM raise error just without tuning and parallel processing

According to [How to Use Lightgbm with Tidymodels](https://blog.rmhogervorst.nl/blog/2020/08/27/how-to-use-lightgbm-with-tidymodels-framework/)

> In contrast to XGBoost, both lightgbm and catboost are very capable of handling categorical variables (factors) and so you don’t need to turn variables into dummies (one hot encode), in fact you shouldn’t do it, it makes everything slower and might give you worse performance.

```
library(treesnip) # lightgbm & catboost connector
m.lgbm <- boost_tree() %>% #trees = tune(), min_n = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode(mode = 'classification') %>% 
  set_engine('lightgbm')
wf.lgbm <- workflow() %>% add_recipe(rec) %>% add_model(m.lgbm)
res.lgbm <- fit_resamples(wf.lgbm,resamples = cv.folds)
```

```
Warning message:
All models failed. See the `.notes` column. 

     res.lgbm$.notes[[1]]

internal: Error in pkg_list[[1]]: subgroup out of bounds
```

Comment: same issue here, any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `tune_grid` without `doParallel` - there seems to be a conflict between LightGBM and `tune_grid` which both want to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

For others that may come across this post in the future:

The [bonsai package](https://github.com/tidymodels/bonsai) follows up on the treesnip package and addresses known issues with tuning in parallel.

For those who utilize `last_fit()` from tune with the `"lightgbm"` engine, users [will need tune v1.0.0.9000 or greater](https://github.com/tidymodels/tune/pull/545).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved with:

```
set_dependency("boost_tree", eng = "lightgbm", "treesnip")
```